# How to import visjs in project jhipster with angular

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

Execute:

```
npm install vis --save
npm install @types/vis --save-dev
```

I just add visjs to my node modules so now I would like to use visjs.
But when I try to start the project with "yarn start", the error jumps:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/eduardo/idea/planning/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any idea why this happens? What is the correct way to add Visjs to my jhipster project?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did it work before you added vis? Can you include your package.json dependencies? This error seems to indicate that you are missing webpack.

Comment: yes, it worked before adding vis

Comment: I found the problem, when I run the command "npm install vis --save" it removes everything that is inside the "webpack-dev-server" module, why? I do not know.